# How to load json so that it has polish letters

Tags: python, json

I have a json saved in a txt file. It is available here https://github.com/szczor/sharing/blob/master/bus_stops.txt. In the txt file there are some names which contain polish letters, they are encoded, for example there is Starzy\u0144skiego which should be Starzyńskiego. My question is what kind of encoding is this and how can i load it so that it has proper names when loaded to python. Here is the code I use to load it.

```
import os
import json

path = os.getcwd()
path_to_data = os.path.join(path, 'data')

with open(os.path.join(path_to_data, 'bus_stops.txt'),encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work fine, assuming `bus_stops.txt` is valid JSON. `json.load` decodes a JSON string as a Python `str` value. Here's a similar example:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('"Starzy\\u0144skiego"')
'Starzyńskiego'
```

(You can see that the argument to `loads` is the JSON encoding of the name using `print(json.dumps('Starzyńskiego'))`. The double backslash above is due to how Python displays a string containing a backslash.)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, then I do not know what is wrong with the file, I tried using 'loads' as you mention instead of 'load' with 'with open(os.path.join(path_to_data, 'bus_stops.txt')) as json_file:
    data = json.loads(json_file.read())' but still getting weird names.

Comment: Please post a *small* sample of the file that doesn't decode the way you want. Either it's not properly encoded, or you are misinterpreting the result.